# How to window each incoming PubSub message into a new window?

Tags: python, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io

I'm using a few Google Cloud Platform services (Dataflow, Cloud Storage, PubSub) and have the scenario:

- A number of apps publish paths to CSV files on GCS to a PubSub topic.
- In a streaming Beam pipeline written in Python, we `beam.io.ReadFromPubSub` and process each input file as a whole in a DoFn (each `process(elem)` call gets a single PubSub message).
- This works fine for the most part, but as files grow we'd like to parallelize file processing by reading them with the Dataframe API (`read_csv(...).to_pcollection(...)`), processing each record in the file with `ParDo`, then passing the original file path as a side input to later stages.

The problem here is that `ReadFromPubSub` results in an unbounded PCollection and I don't understand how it exactly triggers processing. The simple `ReadFromPubSub | ProcessFile` pipeline works as long as each stage returns a single output for each input, but I need to make sure `ReadFromPubSub` outputs windows containing **exactly** one message each to feed the Dataframe API readers with the input file path.

I think the best way to do this is with global windows and an AfterCount trigger, but it triggers on at least N elements, not exactly - there doesn't seem to be a way to force a trigger on the first element right away. Is there a way to enforce single-element windows?

Comment: Can you share your windows desinition? Did you think to create session windows with the filename as session ID?

Comment: I'd like to use the Dataframe API, so I think I just need to need to have the path available as a side input to the Dataframe API and later stages with `file_path = pvalue.AsSingleton(file_path_pcoll)`, then use it  `elems = pipeline | read_csv(file_path).to_pcollection()` and that's it?

Comment: As for session windows, not sure how it's supposed to work, as all APIs expect some sort of a timestamp/time window to put stuff in there.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you could use the DataFrame API's read_csv in this way, it currently only accepts a string file path (potentially a glob with *s). We could modify it to allow you to use a PCollection<String> with file paths, but we'd need a way to read a sample of the data at pipeline construction time.

Comment: I see... well, I'll do it the nasty way and do parallelization on file level only. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Beam does not have a direct way to do this. Originally you would get a `PCollection<File>` which would be transformed into a `PCollection<Element>`. You would loose information regarding the file name at this point so you need to explicitly track this.

I can suggest some workarounds but not sure whether these will exactly match your use case.

1. Include filename (or a hash of the filename) in the input data somehow in each record. This will give a direct way to determine the filename from a given record
2. Use a transform that preserves the filename. For example, [textio.ReadFromTextWithFilename](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/da6d54f84eee7a3431990406c0b59e1426f463df/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/textio.py#L681).
3. Keep a mapping from <window, filenames> (for example in Beam state) and refer to this when needed. You will know the potential list of files when the window closes but will have to further narrow down to a single file somehow to map single elements to file names in downstream stages (using an `AfterCount` trigger as you mentioned might simplify this).